# Error Reading Private Key from Certificate

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate

I wrote a simple c# console app that just tries to read the private key of a x509 cert,

The code is:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection cers = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "cert", false);
if (cers.Count > 0)
{
    X509Certificate2 cer = cers[0];
   
    try
    {
        if (cer.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Private key:");
            Console.WriteLine(cer.GetRSAPrivateKey().ToXmlString(false));
        }

    }
    catch (CryptographicException)
    {      
        string currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        Console.WriteLine("This cert has a private key and this user, " + currentUser + ", was unable to access it.");
    }
};
store.Close();
```

If I run as admin, it work fine.
Otherwise, I get a read permission error.

I used the mmc to give Full Access to my account and even tried giving full access to Everybody (for testing) but same result. The cert does not seem to honor the permissions set.

Am I missing a step?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to make sure that the user running the application has actually the permissions to read both the file and also has rx permissions to all directories leading to this file

Comment: Thanks for responding. I thought I had done that ( including the MavchineKeys directory and files ) but I guess I missed something as when I went back over everything it works.

Comment: An installed certificate can be right clicked inside MMC and you can set up "Manage private keys" where you can set up the permissions for reading the particular certificate in question.